# Send app invite requests to friends via Javascript SDK

Tags: facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-invite

How do I send facebook app invites to multiple friends of the authenticated user via Javascript SDK (I'm  not using the facebook Request dialogs because I need a slightly customized dialog whereby I could allow a different action for those friends that are already users of my app).

Also I want to clarify that my app is *not* a game but an webapp like StackOverflow itself but I allowed it to be  a Canvas app on facebook(*just to be eligible to send app notification, do I need to consider more seriously when making it as a canvas app, downsides?*)

*Thirdly,* Am I eligible being a webapp(which is not a game) to send invites on behalf of users & other notifications to user?   I ask this because most of the places I saw requests docs, it mentioned for games not general webapps/websites.

Comment: Invites can only be send using the Requests dialog. And the sole purpose of a canvas app must not be to just redirect the user out of Facebook.

Comment: _“Can I read the docs before asking?”_ – not only you could, but you _should_. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/requests/